# opportunity's invoice in PDF should viewed in related project tab,in attachments.when order and contract formed for opportunity's quote.Any approache?

Tags: salesforce

Opportunity full Invoice pdf should view in related to project object, when order and contract is created for Quote of related opportunity.It Should View in project object, in its related tabs files/Note and Attachment. give possible approaches

Tired for visual force page calling from trigger approach is not working

Answer (score 0):

What's your data model? What's the relation between opps and projects? where is the PDF generated, on quote, opp or what?

Experiment in the Lightning App Builder (drag & drop editor) whether you can drop a related list (or enhanced related list) related not to this project but this project's Opportunity?

Like here I'm editing Contract lightning page and I dropped a rel. list but I set it to not "use this contract" and I made it go "up" to Account (well, "Account name" but that's just label for the `Contract.AccountId` field).

[image]

If this doesn't work (for example you don't have nice easy Project -> go up -> Opportunity)... Either a coded component (you tried with VF, ok, share what you have?) or...

You could always inject a piece of code into when the file is created (ideally you already have a button click on Opportunity or something like that... but worst case could even build a trigger on ContentVersion or ContentDocumentLink and inspect if the file is opportunity-ish by looking at ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId or ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId). And if you detect it's this PDF you need - cross-share it to the Project too by inserting new ContentDocumentLink

**Edit**

You said you have a button on Opportunity and VF page behind that button. Would be nice to see what code you have behind that button (if any) - or does the button just render the PDF now?

I'd do something like

1. Create a VF page with renderAs="pdf" you're 100% happy with. It'll be accepting opportunity Id as url parameter, right?
2. Experiment with code snippet below, for now in Developer Console.
3. If it's any good - that code snippet should be run as either another small VF page button or headless (no UI, just execute code) [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader/documentation)/[LWC quick action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions-headless.html).

The snippet I'd start with is something like this. No promises it compiles but should set you on the right path

```apex
Id opportunityId = '006...'; // will be passed from standardController or whatever;
Opportunity o = [SELECT Name, 
    (SELECT Id FROM Projects__r LIMIT 1) 
    FROM Opportunity 
    WHERE Id = :opportunityId]; // what's the link between oppty and project? who has lookup to who? I'm assuming it's from project to opp

PageReference pdf = Page.MyOpportunityPdf; // your PDF page name 
pdf.getParameters().put('id', opportunityId); 
Blob b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
System.debug(b);

// 1 insert the PDF and link it to the opportunity 1st
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
    Title = o.Name;
    PathOnClient = o.Name + '.pdf',
    VersionData = b,
    FirstPublishLocationId = o.Id
);
insert cv;

// 2 cross-link same file to record
if(!o.Projects__r.isEmpty()){
    cv = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cv.Id];
    insert new ContentDocumentLink(
        LinkedEntityId = o.Projects__r[0].Id,
        ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId,
        ShareType = 'V',
        Visibility = 'AllUsers'
    );
}
```

Comment: By using VF page created button on opportunity object , with in one click of that button that pdf should appear in related project object in project's notes and attachment section.